# Exporting /writing to Excel tabs from a Multi-Index Pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, excel, list-comprehension, pandas-groupby

I'd like to split/slice a multi-index dataframe by the first index '0' into a dataframe for each level of the first index (for example below there would be 4 dataframes). I would then like to export each dataframe into a separate tab in EXCEL. The most important problem I'd like help on is how to write a loop or list comprehension that would split the multi-index dataframe into separate dataframes.

The Example Dataframe:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np


arrays = [
    np.array(['bar', 'bar', 'baz', 'baz', 'foo', 'foo', 'qux', 'qux']),
    np.array(['one', 'two', 'one', 'two', 'one', 'two', 'one', 'two'])
]
index = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(list(zip(*arrays)), names=['IDX1', 'IDX2'])
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(3, 8), index=['A', 'B', 'C'], columns=index)
df2 = df.T
```

The resulting df2 multiindex example dataframe:

[image]

I'd like to create a dataframe for each level of IDX1 and export each 1 into a separate tab.

```
# Create a Pandas Excel writer using XlsxWriter as the engine.
writer = pd.ExcelWriter('pandas_multiple.xlsx', engine='xlsxwriter')

# Write each dataframe to a different worksheet.
df1.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='bar')
df2.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='baz')
df3.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='foo')
df4.to_excel(writer,sheet_name = 'qux')
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use

```
for idx in df2.index.get_level_values('IDX1').unique():
    temp = df2.loc[idx]
    temp.to_excel(writer, sheet_name=idx)
```

Loop over all unique values of the index by using [`get_level_values`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Index.get_level_values.html), then use [`.loc`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html) to select the sub-`DataFrame`. You can then write this sub-`DataFrame` to excel using your predefined Writer.